# Javascript injection limitations?

Tags: javascript, url, browser, console, code-injection

I'm working on a website where users can play javascript games. I've been learning js online but I'm far from being an expert. To prevent cheating in games, i have implemented all of the logic using php and session variables. Now my question is: just how much can users do with js injection?

I know it can be used to edit/view variables and values but can users go as far as commenting out my already written functions and writing their own? if this is possible then it seems like there will be no way to prevent cheating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes they actually can. You can't prevent cheating client-side, thats why you need strong logic server-side.

If you look at projects like greasemonkey or tampermonkey, those extensions allow you to easily inject javascript to any website.

What to do then?

numeric values have to be serverside: money, hp, mana, turns, number of important things displayed on screen. And then you have to check for logic when the client send you actions: Can he gain that amount of money where he is?

time-based actions can be a good measure too: how many actions per second is he doing?, why he took 10 minuts answering a 1 minut test?

This is pseudo-pseudo code, as I don't know the nature of your game, but it should get you started.

Comment: Yea I saved all values server side with code in place to check if so many points can be gained so quickly. I was experimenting with a simple snake game and the cheat protection seems solid. What I was worried about was someone writing their own js function to autonomously play play the game making the best possible moves and never crashing into the wall.

Comment: You're doing a simple game. It will get cheated on. Complex mmorpgs by big companies get cheated by bots too, it's nothing to be ashamed of.